# I am trying to put avro message using kafka streams but it is putting as a binary data type-java

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to take jsonSerde as input from topics and should process the record and need to put it as Avro message in different topics using kafka streams.The output looks to be binary and the data is not in actual JSON format.Looks, like it is using default bytearrayserde for value and key.I don't know why but I'm providing the serializer as SpecificAvroSerde.

```
        private final static JsonSerde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = new JsonSerde<JsonNode>(JsonNode.class);

        private static Map<String, Object> props;
        //Serde of specific record
        private static  SpecificAvroSerde<SpecificRecord> productValueSerde;



   @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
        public StreamsConfig kafkaStreamsConfig()
                throws UnknownHostException {
            props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,
                    "*****processor-3");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:29092,localhost:19092,localhost:39092");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
                    "http://localhost:18081");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients"
                    + ".consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
            productValueSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<SpecificRecord>();
            productValueSerde.configure((Collections.singletonMap(
                    AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
                    "http://localhost:18081")),false);
            return new StreamsConfig(props);
        }


        @Bean
        public KStream<JsonNode,JsonNode> KStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder){

            KStream<JsonNode,JsonNode> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream("localtest",Consumed.with(jsonSerde, jsonSerde));
            try {
                KStream<JsonNode,SpecificRecord> avroStream = stream.flatMap((K,V)->actNationalPaperHelper.mapToCoreAvro(K, V));
                //avroStream.flatMap((K,V)->System.out.println(V); return avroStream));
                avroStream.through("serdetest16",Produced.with(jsonSerde, productValueSerde));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            return stream;

        }
   T
```